# JAX-RS web.xml deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, weblogic

Using a JAX-RS aware container, for example an app server like Weblogic,
what's the difference in configuring JAX-RS capabilities in the web.xml this way:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                myapp.server,
                myapp.server.boundaries
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and using the Application.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
public class ShoppingApplication extends Application {
   // complete
}
```

Comment: Generally, there is no difference. It's just a matter of preferences.

Comment: In the latter method, How do I kinow what JAX-RS implementation I'm using ?

Comment: @GionJh - the key is that you shouldn't care which implementation - you could switch from Jersey to RestEasy or anything else by just changing containers.

Comment: If I want to use a different implementation from the one the app server ships with, is the first method mandatory ?

Comment: what version of weblogic did you using?